# Stop Game Speed Hack

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app where I open a HTML5 game in WebView, its a single player game where we match 2 players and who ever scores more wins the game. This has a time limit. There are users who use speed hack X8 Speeder for one. I am trying to find how do I avoid this.

How do I detect if a particular app is installed on the phone. Even if they change the app name

How do it detect if my APK has been patched or modified.

Any help would be great.

Regards

Mitsy

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I'd try to verify game sessions on the backend. When game completes, your app sends the complete log of what happened to your server which then analyzes it. If the log was generated by a script (like this, for example: https://x8speeder.com/?p=77), it will have very repeated and detectable sequences. You can then discard this score and not put it on the leaderboard.

Comment: The games are third party. Except the score and game state nothing is being passed. I basically want to know how in flutter i can check if my apk is patched/tampered/injected and how to find if a particular app is installed on the mobile

Comment: @Opium_Mitsy: ah, it's not you who makes the games. Yep, that makes sense.

Comment: Just an update to all sharing with community. I used flutter_appavailability | Flutter Package to find if a particular package is installed and made it dynamic from backend. So when ever i dont want users to user my app due to a particular hacking app installed I can just show a message and shut the application

Comment: @Opium_Mitsy: you should post this as a self-answer